# Python 3.7 Help on Selenium-Element could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.7

I am getting this error:

"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view"

This is the code i am using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="next"]').click()
```

This is from the inspector:

[image]

Can you please let me know how to click on "Next"?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this element is located out of the initially visible screen when you open that page with Selenium.
Try scrolling it into the view and then clicking it with the following code:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)

pager = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="next"]')
actions.move_to_element(pager).perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
pager.click()
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer. I tried it but i am getting the same message.

Comment: can you share a link to that page? We need to see what is actually happens there

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of "accept cookies" banner on the footer?

Comment: Hi, thanks again. The link will not work as it requires username/password to load the page. No, there is no any accept cookies or something similar. I can use code to click on other links on the page, but not on this one.

Comment: Instead of `'//li[@class="next"]'` please try '//li[@class="next"]/a'. maybe this is because `a` element should get the click?

Comment: Great, happy to know. This seems making sense. elements normally getting the click actions are of `button`, `div`, `a`, `label` types.